# In C# should try-catch be used for is-numeric testing?

Tags: c#

I have heard that using exception trapping is not a recommended practice for number testing.

For example:

```
bool isnumeric
try
{
int i = int.parse(textbox1.text);
isnumeric = true;
}

catch {isnumenric=false}
```

Is there some other way that I could test for numbers in C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes try using

```
int i;    
bool success = Int32.TryParse(textBox1.text, out i);
```

The **TryParse** method basically does what you are doing above.

Comment: Also don't forget double.TryParse() and decimal.TryParse(), since those are numeric as well.

Comment: However, TryParse() doesn't just mimic his initial code, where the exception is just swallowed.  It's a little different, in that an exception is never thrown in the first place.  It's more likely that Int32.Parse() calls TryParse() and throws if false is returned.

Comment: if you look at mine a couple answers down, it has the same functionality

Comment: @napinski: Don't sweat it... My answer is identical, and was before this one chronologically. It's all down to the luck of the draw :)

Comment: If you like the ternary operator, you can make it pretty terse:
int value;
int default = -1;
return Int32.TryParse(text, out value) ? value : default;

Comment: Another thing to note: if string turns out to NOT be an integer, you'll find out about an order of magnitude faster.  I swapped out Int.Parse for Int32.TryParse in a key place in one of the apps I was working on, and it dropped startup time from 40 seconds to 3.

Comment: Also keep in mind that int.TryParse will not work for integers of a certain size, you will need long.TryParse if the number > 2,147,483,647

Answer (score 10):

Use the built-in [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

E.g.

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Use int.TryParse, double.TryParse, etc. instead, which all return a boolean.

Alternately, there's an IsNumeric function buried in the VB assemblies (in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll) that you can also call from your C# code:

bool Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(value)

Comment: Perhaps someone who dislikes VB

Comment: Probably. Should note: if you're using a pre-2.0 .NET, the VB way is the easiest way (barring exception handling), since TryParse didn't exist at that point.

Answer (score 5):

TryParse()

```
int i;
if(Int32.TryParse(someString,out i))
{
    //now use i because you know it is valid
    //otherwise, TryParse would have returned false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int result = -1;
bool isNumeric = Int32.TryParse(text, out result);
```

isNumeric will be true if the number is numeric, false otherwise; if the number is numeric, result will have the numeric value of the number.

Comment: hi DrjOkepu, the variable has to be uninitialized in order to use "out"?

Comment: Nick Berardi: As DannuSmurf said, it does not require to be unitialized. In fact, even though it can be unitialized, I really suggest to initialize all your variables to *some* value even though you will assign some value to it later on. It is just good practice.

Comment: That is my bad, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx I got the reverse of "ref" mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

bool TryParse(string, out int)

It will return a bool that is true if it was able to parse the integer, and the out parameter will contain the integer (if it was successful with the parsing).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to do number testing and do not need the integer number, you may use the function below. This is faster than Int32.TryParse(...) methods.

Edit for Barry Fandango: Handles negative numbers now. This is only for testing integers.

```
    public static bool IsNumber(string s)
    {
       if (s == null || s.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (s[0] == '-')
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!char.IsDigit(s[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (char c in s)
            {
                if (!char.IsDigit(c))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please see edit note. It handles negative numbers now. This is only for testing integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the integer then Int32.TryParse(...) is what you want else
Information.IsNumeric(...) (From the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll) if you don't care what the actual integer is.